# jQuery LightBox and Superbox is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

On click of image, I want it to pop-out with the transparent bacground.

I tried using both LightBox and SuperBox, but in both the cases although image pops out, I am facing below issues,

1. It is not showing close button, title etc.
2. It it showing image path in the URL and thus i have to click browser back button to go back to website
3. It is not showing transparent background (I dont want to hide my web page when image pop-out).
   I am new to jQuery.

My DOM looks like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".testing").click(function() {
        $('.testing').css('border', "3px solid white");
        var newsrc = $(this).attr("src");
        $('.testingMain').attr('src', newsrc);
        $(this).css('border', "3px solid grey");
    });
    $(".testing").click(function() {
        $('#gallery a').lightBox();
    });
});​
</script>

     <div id="leftmemberPan">
           <a href="/MyApp/images/${article.images[0].imageName}"><img src="/MyApp/images/${article.images[0].imageName}" alt="/MyApp/img/image_unavailable.jpg" class="testingMain"/></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace href`s # with your image link

```
<a href="#"><img src="/MyApp/images/${image.imageName}" alt="/MyApp/img/image_unavailable.jpg" class="testing"/></a>
```

I dont know it it is intended but you are binding click to an img element not an a (i believe it should be so).

As an lightBox init you should make

```
$('#leftmemberPan a').lightbox();
```